# TypeScript Styled-Components Theme property returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I added a theme to my React app however when I try to to set the property on my component it doesn't work. I tried to log the result of `props.theme.red` and is returning `undefined`. I tried to search for an answer but didn't find any. Can you please help me?

**styled.d.ts**

```
// import original module declarations
import "styled-components";

// import custom theme
import theme from "../utils/theme";

// extend the module declarations using custom theme type
type Theme = typeof theme;

declare module "styled-components" {
  export interface DefaultTheme extends Theme {}
}
```

**theme.tsx**

```
const theme = {
  red: "#ff0000",
} as const;

export default theme;
```

**App.tsx**

```
const MyHeading = styled.h1`
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.red};
`;

const App = () => {
  return <MyHeading>Heading</MyHeading>;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const App = () => {
  return <MyHeading theme={theme}>Heading</MyHeading>;
};
```

I think you missed `theme`